# Initial value problem solving

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have solved this initial value problem and need to find an $a$ that separates the solutions that become negative from those that become positive

$$9y''-12y'+4y=0$$

$y(0)=a>0, y'(0)=-1$

I solved the equation and here is the result

$y=ae^{\frac{2}{3}t}+(-1-\frac {2}{3}a)te^{\frac{2}{3}t}$

How do I determine that value of $a$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So then when $t=0, t<0$ I can conclude that the solution is positive and otherwise negative? Is it all? @Amzoti

Comment: See my last edit, I think you might have miss-read the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question asks to find the value of $a$ that separates solution that become positive from those that become negative. For large values of $t$, the $te^{\frac{2}{3}t}$ term will dominate the $e^{\frac{2}{3}t}$ term. So for the value to eventually become positive all that is needed it that
$$-\frac{2}{3}a-1>0$$
so $$a<-\frac{3}{2}$$

---

Edit: By the way, I have this same question in my book in ODE's: "Elementary Differential Equations and Boundary Values Problems", and there it is mentioned with

$$9y''+12y'+4y=0$$
which makes more sense given the restriction on $a$

Comment: Isn't it $-\frac{2}{3}a-1$?

Comment: @MarionCrane Yes sorry

Comment: @Amzoti Ah you're right. Well in that case there is not solution, unless MarionCrane made a mistake in calculating the solution to the ODE.

Comment: Well in my opinion the statement "solution that become positive" means that we are talking about the behavior as $t\to\infty$, in which case I don't see how there can be a solution that becomes positive.

Comment: @Amzoti See my edit, I think she might have miss-read the question

Comment: I think I misread it. Sorry guys. i hate myself

Comment: I am reading from that textbook

Comment: So, if it were the case that there was plus sign, then would I use your method? @user2520938

Comment: @MarionCrane Yes you would. Wether the solution becomes negative or positive eventually is only determined by the sign of the coefficient of the fastest growing term in the solution. So in this case that is $te^{\frac{2}{3}t}$. So you only need to find out when that coefficient is positive and when it is negative.

Answer (score 0):

the answer to your question is there is no such $a.$

here are few things you can verify for any $a > 0$:

(a) $\lim_{t \to \infty} y = -\infty, \lim_{t \to -\infty} y  = 0$

(b) $y$ has only one critical number $t_0 < 0$ such that $y'(t) < 0$ for $t > t_0$ and $y'(t) > 0$ for $t < t_0$

(c) there a number $t_1 = \frac{3a}{3+2a} > 0$ such that $y(t) > 0$ for $t < t_1$ and $y(t) < 0$ for $t > t_1$